# Finding out the population size

Tags: statistics

If Player A is ranked 5230 in a pool of players and Player A is in the 98.2% percentile, would it be possible to tell how many players there are?

Would additional info be needed, such as the type of distribution? Is it only possible to tell for normal or flat distributions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume not... if Player A is ranked 5230, that means that there are 5229 players in the top 1.8%. So we have that
$$\frac{1.8}{100} = \frac{5229}{x}$$
So $x$, the number of players, is $290500$.

Comment: The percentile is probably rounded, so this number is only good to $\pm 5\%$, but a good approach.